# ColdFusion cfmail how do I keep the formatting

Tags: email, coldfusion

In my ColdFusion program I create email (HTML/CSS) for one or many recipients, and place it in a .cfm file.  The email is nicely formatted.  When I run the saved file as a program, the cfmail tag sends the email along to whomever, and that is all working.  However, along the way, my formatting gets lost.  I understand that there is no reason for my local CSS to be functioning when the email gets to its target.  But it would be nice if I could preserve the formatting I started with.

Does anyone have a suggestion about how I might do this.

Comment: Ask a direct question: post some code which demonstrates your issue, and provide the output & explanation of why it's not what you want. http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not including the attribute `type="html"` in your `cfmail` tag, that could be affecting the formatting of your email.  Also, within the `cfmail` tag, embed your style within in addition to your content.  For example:

```
<cfmail from="foo@bar.com" to="foobar@bar.com" subject"test" server="mymailserver" type="html">
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        .test { color: ##cc0000; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="test">This email is in red</div>
    </body>
  </html>
</cfmail>
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I think the opening and closing html tags are redundant.

Comment: This looks pretty straightforward, and I can easily do it.  Never would have ocurred to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Styling emails can be tricky as it's different across clients - there are whole blog articles devoted to this. For example, styles in the head section get ignored in some clients and recognised in others. Sadly, inline styles seems to be the "best" approach.

There is a good overview on the campaign monitor website of what works if which clients:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Mailchimp have a handy tool which will inline styles for you based on your HTML/CSS:
http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

It's also worth including a plain text version for maximum compatibility. You can do that like this:

```
<cfmail to="someone@somewhere.xyz"
        from="me@here.xyz"
        subject="Hello!"
        type="html">
   <cfmailpart type="text/plain" wraptext="60">
     Hello,
     This is plain text version
   </cfmailpart>
   <cfmailpart type="text/html">
     <h3>Hello</h3>
     <p>This is <b style="color:red;">HTML</b> version</p>
   </cfmailpart>
</cfmail>
```

Comment: The references are very useful.  Glad you provided them.